# Regularization strategy in Keras

Tags: keras, regression, regularized

I have trying to setup a non-linear regression problem in Keras. Unfortunately, results show that overfitting is occurring. Here is the code,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(number_of_neurons, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(outdim, activation='linear'))
Adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam, metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, batch_size=500, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, verbose=2 , initial_epoch=0)
```

The results without regularization is shown here [Without regularization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y226V.png). The mean absolute error for training is much less compared to validation, and both have a fixed gap which is a sign of over-fitting.

L2 regularization was specified for each layer like so,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(number_of_neurons, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(int(number_of_neurons), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(outdim, activation='linear'))
Adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam, metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, batch_size=500, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, verbose=2 , initial_epoch=0)
```

The results for these are shown here [L2 regularized result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg6V2.png). The MAE for test is close to training which is good. However, the MAE for training is poor  at 0.03 (without regularization it was much lower at 0.0028).

What can i do to reduce the training MAE with regularization?

Answer (score 13):

Based on your results, it looks like you need to find the right amount of regularization to balance training accuracy with good generalization to the test set. This may be as simple as reducing the L2 parameter. Try reducing lambda from 0.001 to 0.0001 and comparing your results.

If you can't find a good parameter setting for L2, you could try dropout regularization instead. Just add `model.add(Dropout(0.2))` between each pair of dense layers, and experiment with the dropout rate if necessary. A higher dropout rate corresponds to more regularization.